# debug library loaded with ctypes using gdb

Tags: python, debugging, gdb, ctypes

I loaded in python a C library X.so, that I compiled with these flags.

```
GDBFLAGS = -gdwarf-2 -g3 -O0 -ggdb
```

and I call some of its non-static functions from python , using ctypes.

I wish debugging the C library X.so. Some function from X.so crashes sometimes, not all the time, and I wish monitoring the execution using gdb.

I use linux-gnu. How can I debug ctypes ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use "gdb python" and run your program as usual.  Then when it crashes, debug as normal.

BTW I recommend using just "-g3".  Don't use "-gdwarf-2", this does the wrong thing nowadays -- DWARF 2 is quite old actually and the default is newer now.

Comment: gdb should be set up with [libpython.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7ff62415e426/Tools/gdb/libpython.py), such as is installed by Debian's [python3.3-dbg](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python3.3-dbg) package. It pretty prints Python objects and installs the commands `py-print`, `py-locals`, `py-list`, `py-bt`, `py-bt-full`, `py-up`, and `py-down`.