# Debug library loaded with ctypes using LLDB

Tags: python, debugging, ctypes, lldb

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261745/debug-library-loaded-with-ctypes-using-gdb), how do I use LLDB to debug a library that I'm loading with [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)?

I can start it in the debugger with

```
$ lldb -- python myscript.py
```

But then I'd like to set a breakpoint on a particular function in the C library. Writing the following fails:

```
(lldb) breakpoint set -f fft.c -l 78
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
```

Running `image list` doesn't show my library. How do I tell LLDB to load the library?

Also, once it's loaded how can I verify that LLDB loaded the debug symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you haven't run your program to the point where it has loaded the library containing code from fft.c yet?

That shouldn't be a problem for lldb.  Every time a new shared library is loaded, lldb checks all the extant breakpoints to see if they find any matches in the new shared library.  So you should be able to set the breakpoint, then run, and when the library gets loaded, a new location will get added.  If that isn't true, then please file a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com.

lldb actually will put out a notice that this has happened to the command line.

You can watch the shared libraries load if you wish by setting:

```
(lldb) settings set target.process.stop-on-sharedlibrary-events true
```

But that isn't necessary to get lldb to scan all the newly loaded libraries for breakpoint matches.

Comment: Correct, the library hasn't been run to load the library yet. That explains the `(pending)` in the above message. Thanks.